# Using multiple OR in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I need to write a query which should check if there is at least one column which has a value greater than 0 (>0) in the table. Currently, I have written a 'WHERE' clause with multiple OR conditions. I suspect that this may not be the best way of doing this (may be use SUM?). Seeking opinion from SQL experts.

```
WHERE raw_0 >0 OR raw_1 >0 OR raw_2 >0 OR raw_3 >0 OR raw_4>0
```

Comment: Could the content of your raw columns be negative?

Comment: Your existing query is the easiest to write and understand (and probably the best for the optimizer as there's no calculation involved)

Comment: @schlonzo the values cannot be negative. They are 0 or greater than 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use

   ```
   WHERE (raw_0 >0 OR raw_1 >0 OR raw_2 >0 OR raw_3 >0 OR raw_4>0);
   ```

   As per your question. As dnoeth commented,  is the easiest to write and understand (and probably the best for the optimizer as there's no calculation involved)
2. Alternatively you can use:

   ```
   WHERE ((RAW_0 + RAW_1 + RAW_2 + RAW_3) > 0);
   ```

   The above condition would be satisfied IF and only IF, atleast one of the values is >0.
3. You can also use concat operator to concat the strings and check if the concatenated string has value other than zero:

   ```
   WHERE TO_NUMBER ( RAW_0 || RAW_1 || RAW_2 || RAW_3 ) > 0
   ```

   Test data for 3rd query:

   ```
   select 'YES value' data from dual where TO_NUMBER ( 1 || 2) > 0 ;
   select 'NO value' data from dual where TO_NUMBER ( 0 || 0) > 0 ;
   ```

Comment: This does only work, if the value in the raw columns cannot be negative.

Comment: @schlonzo: User has specified that value is not negative in his comments.

Comment: Yes you are right. He posted that after your answer. But might be good to know for others.

Comment: Yes sure @schlonzo.. Thank you for highlighting and upvoting too.

Answer (score 1):

If the values can only be non-negative, as in one of the OP comment then you can check the multiplication

```
WHERE raw_0 * raw_1 * raw_2 * raw_3 * raw_4 > 0
```

but that will check if every value as positive. To check if only one is positive we can negate this logic using the `SIGN` function

```
WHERE (1 - SIGN(raw_0)) 
    * (1 - SIGN(raw_1)) 
    * (1 - SIGN(raw_2)) 
    * (1 - SIGN(raw_3)) 
    * (1 - SIGN(raw_4)) = 0
```

`(1 - SIGN(value))` return 1 when the value is zero and 0 when the value is positive, so if at least one value is positive the product will be 0.